# What to do with condescending non-answers that violate the Code of Conduct?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer, rude-or-abusive, unfriendly-or-unkind

I recently encountered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53073685/4032703):

[image]

If that was a comment, I'd just flag it as "unfriendly or unkind" for being a put-down. That being said, since this is posted as an answer, how should we flag it? It's definitely worse than NAA, but is it "bad enough" to red-flag it as rude/abusive?

Comment: I'd probably just use NAA and a downvote. They won't last very long.

Comment: Oh, I definitely downvoted it - just not sure whether to go with NAA or rude/abusive for the flag.

Comment: Saying ["your answer is in another castle"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) is not an answer.

Comment: Answers like this should be looked at on a case by case basis. In the case of this specific answer, if I had seen it while it was still around I would have flagged it as rude.

Comment: Is it rude though? I mean, yeah it is an abuse of the answer feature, but looks like a brand new user posting a not-needed comment as an answer. That happens all the time and usually isn't considered rude.

Comment: @TinyGiant If it was a comment, I probably would've just flagged it as unkind.

Comment: But how is it unkind. It's misguided and not needed, but unkind? It doesn't actually say RTFM, it just says the answer is in the docs. People with lots of rep say similar things all the time, albeit more specific, but yeah.

Comment: Guys, just be objective and unfeeling (?): what would you have done if the only flags were NAA, spam, vlq and rude/abusive. I liked when it was about facts, not feelings.

Comment: @Nathan I think that's a bit of a stretch. I could see myself coming to the same conclusion in many cases and wondering the same thing. _"What's the return value of `Object.values()`?"_ ... _"Why don't you just read the documentation on it? It says what it is right there at the top."_ I might not say exactly that, and I'd probably just link to the documentation and ask for clarification on what it was they were actually after, but I can see how someone would get there without meaning to be rude or dismissive.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Many people don't care about how they write and write without capitalization, with casual language, and without punctuation. Sure, it's annoying to read, but it's hardly rude. It just reads as "I'm lazy," but that doesn't make it rude and definitely not worth a rude flag.

Comment: @Nathan Again, that's a stretch. All-lower-case, that happens all the time, not usually considered rude. Overly-casual use of "man", ok maybe, but really? Straight to rude/abusive? Lack of punctuation, again that happens all the time and is not usually considered rude. Lack of anything at all specific, the only thing specific in my example comment was saying "right there at the top", which isn't very specific, still not seeing how that is rude. I see no expression of "exactly how little they cared about the questioner and ... their solving efforts thus far", or was that hyperbole? ...

Comment: As far as the grossly low-effort post... yeah it's low quality and doesn't show much effort, but it's a first post from a brand new user. It is not uncommon for new users to post comments as answers due to the comment restriction, and they are usually not considered rude for that. I'm still not getting where the rude part is coming from.

Comment: I am mildly curious about the downvotes on this (just for my personal reference).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is one of those types of answers I think the Low Quality Posts queue was designed for. So, go ahead and flag it as NAA or VLQ so it gets punted to the queue, let the reviewers eat it up (since most LQP reviews recommend deletion for short and poorly written "answers" just like this).

If that doesn't work... you know what? Flag it for moderator attention. Ask for me if you need to. I eat these types of low-effort answers for breakfast, lunch and dinner. These answers don't need to exist on the site in any way, shape or form. They aren't constructive, don't add any value to the topic at hand, and the author is very unlikely to have any sort of emotional attachment to it, let alone anyone else who has to see it.

On the Code of Conduct side of things, I'd say this falls just afoul of it in the sense that it doesn't take the site, the question, the asker, or itself, seriously. It's not unlikely or unreasonable that readers would find it dismissive and a waste of their time at the very least, if not condescending. Certainly it doesn't come off to me as rude, so rude/abusive isn't going to be the best flag for it, which is why I recommended NAA/VLQ instead. But I can't call it a sincere attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Nice answer. Not to sure about how you invite to turn the moderator attention flag into a sort of bat-signal though... It didn't work out too well for Batman either that people knew that he was the one taking care of business.

Comment: @Gimby: The only people who will see a custom flag are the flag owner and all the moderators, so it shouldn't be a problem. If any of them spots a flag for me they'll let me know. I'm doing this of my own volition, and so far none of the other moderators have objected. (And that's *Bolt*-Signal to you!)

Comment: @Gimby: There's also my name showing underneath the answer deletions of course... I can always send someone else under the guise of feeling lazy. But no, I think I can handle any flak I get for it. (I can't imagine most I'll get being defensible anyway.)

Comment: Alright Boltman, if you say so ;)